# TFS work item tags (To Delete / Modify ) - Team Foundation Server 2013

Tags: tfs, tags

I have been informed to remove obsolete tags from TFS,Is there is a option to remove tags that are no longer needed?In other words "centralized" method to manage them.
*Pls also note that there are **User stories** & **Bugs** already added to TFS using these obsolete tags.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a minimum of TFS 2013 Update 4 to enable Tag management support from Excel and through the API.